# Is There A Way To Get Street View Coordinates After Gesture?

Tags: ios, google-maps

I'm displaying a Street View (GMSPanoramaView) via Google Maps SDK for iOS in an iPhone/iPad app and I need to get the final position of a Street View after the user has navigated around in it using gestures, so that I can restore it to the exact position the user moved it to.  This is extremely important to be able to do since the Street View is not accurate and often places an address hundreds of yards away from the actual one requested, forcing the user to tap and zoom to move the Street View in front of it.  I don't see any delegate methods or API's to get updated coordinates.  I can easily track the heading, pitch, zoom, and FOV via the GMSPanoramaViewDelegate didMoveCamera method, but that does not give me updated coordinates.  Thus when I restore the Street View using the last heading, pitch, zoom, and FOV values, the Street View displays at the original location but with the heading, pitch, zoom, and FOV applied, which doesn't display the same position as the user expects.  Does anyone know how to get (or track) these coordinates?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement the `panoramaView:(GMSPanoramaView*)view didMoveToPanorama:(GMSPanaorama*)panorama` on the delegate.

On the `GMSPanorama` there's a `CLLocationCoordinate2d` called `coordinate` - voila.

**EDIT**

It also appears that at any point in time to can just get the `panorama` property from the `GMSPanoramaView` and get the `coordinate` from there.

Comment: I did try getting the coordinates from the GMSPanoramaView after moving the street view around to different locations but it always contains the original coordinates.

Comment: What about the delegate method didMoveToPanorama?

Comment: You're correct, the GMSPanoramaView.panorama.coordinate does have the updated value.  I was mistakenly using the original value I had started with.  Thanks!